# CakePHP 3: error when creating migrations

Tags: cakephp, migration, cakephp-3.0

when I try to use this command in CakePHP console :

```
cake migrations create CreatePostsTable
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Application' not found
>   in C:\wamp\
>   www\CookieCMS\vendor\cakephp\migrations\src\MigrationsDispatcher.php
>   on line 22

What could be the cause for the error?

Comment: Have you ran the composer installer? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp

Comment: Yes, in the end I realized that something was wrong with the folder structure of Symfony package, so I reaplaced the vendor/symfony folder with the corresponding folder from the newly installed CakePHP 3 project.